# How to check when useState variable becomes available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have useState variable that gets set based on a Promise that's resolved, how can I access the variable once it been setup
at the moment to get the correct values I have to use a setTimeout function, just wondering if there was a better way of doing that.

```
const FlagScreen = ({ t, i18n, history }) => {
  const [flagAvailability, setFlagAvailability] = useState([]);
  const [showFlags, setShowFlags] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let flagsAvailable = [];
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(flags)) {
      if (key.indexOf(i18n.language) !== -1) {
        for (const v of value) {
          checkForAvailableAgent(`sales_${v}`, LINK_TO_STUDIO, SERVICE_ID)
            .then(res => {
              flagsAvailable[v] = res;
              // Sets the flags availability i.e de: false, en: true
              setFlagAvailability(flagsAvailable);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("an error happened.");
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }, [i18n.language]);

 useEffect(() => {
      //the value of flagAvailability is not available yet, I have to set a timeout function for 
      // 3 seconds for it to be available
      console.log("flag availability: ", Object.entries(flagAvailability));
      for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(flagAvailability)) {
        console.log("key is: ", k);
        if (v === true) {
          setShowFlags(k);
        }
      }
  }, [flagAvailability]);
}

<Container className="h-100">
  <Row className="h-45 mt-5 text-center">
    {ALL_STUDIOS_FLAGS.filter(item => {
        return showFlags.includes(item);
     }).map((item, index) => (
        <Col key={index}>
         <img
          src={require(`../assets/flags/${item}.png`)}
          alt={`${item} flag`}
         />
         <span>{item.toUpperCase()}</span>
       </Col>
    ))}
 </Row>
```

any help would be appreicated,

Comment: Have you tried returning null or a loading page if the variable is null, then using it as normal after?

Comment: I haven't, can you elaborate a little bit more please.

Comment: So write `if(!flagAvailability.length) return null` before you use the variable. Then, once it has loaded, the rest of the code will execute after this if. For example, here's some [code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/AgnV3k4JRw2JY_DbwVw-0g.png) i wrote that fits what i mean

Comment: well doing that produced this error: TypeError: destroy is not a function
    at commitHookEffectList

Comment: [This](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14838#issuecomment-463017684) might help, but it doesnt look like you return anything from your useEffects

Answer (score 0):

The `setFlagAvailability(flagsAvailable);` in the first useEffect will only update the value of flagAvailability in second render

the second useEffect in the first render will only get the initial value of flagAvailability ( I know it's like a circle)

**Every render has its own useEffect and useState**

One of the solutions is to skip the first render in setShowFlags useEffect by creating a useRef flag like this

```
const ref = useRef(false)
const [flagAvailability, setFlagAvailability] = useState(true);
const [showFlags, setShowFlags] = useState(true);

useEffect(()=> {
  if(ref.current){
    ...
    setShowFlags();
    ref.current = false;
  }
},[flagAvailability])

useEffect(() => {
  ...
  setFlagAvailability();
  ref.current = true
},[i18n.language])
```

or you can simple change flagAvailability as useRef cause the refvalue will always be the new value.

```
const flagRef = useRef([]])
const [showFlags, setShowFlags] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  flagRef.current = flagsAvailable
},[i18n.language])

useEffect(()=> {
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(flagRef.current)) {
    setShowFlags();
  }
},[showFlags])
```